# What is the best way to deploy large files using git on Heroku?

Tags: git, github, heroku

I want to use the github deployment on Heroku since I find it very convenient.
I have a machine learning web application deployed using Django which involves a model for inference. My problem is:

1. I do not like to commit large file on git
2. My model is going to change anyway so I do not want all its versions to be tracked
3. I do not want to have to clean my git repo with tools like filter-branch

so what it the best way to deploy large file (~60MB) on Heroku using github deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you load it from a third-party service like Amazon S3 at runtime?

Comment: I am not using such service, can't I kind of upload it at build time?

Comment: Yes, you can upload it at build time and have your application _load it into memory_ at runtime. Maybe it should do that when it starts up. You haven't shared your code, so I'm not sure if the second part is possible (which is why I didn't add an answer), but it's probably worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks, how can you upload it at build time? Whatever my code is, I will be able to load it at run time if I can copy it on heroku slug at build time... but how can I upload it?

Comment: Well I wouldn't suggest copying it to the slug. There are hard limits on slug size, so loading it when your dyno starts up is probably the best option. I have no idea how you're building your application so I can't advise on adding an S3 upload to that process. There are lots of ways to do this; I suggest you start by searching "<build tool> s3 upload" and go from there.

Comment: The size of my model is still limited (takes less memory than my libs) that is why I would like to add it to the slug. Ok, but is there a way to upload it from my local computer and avoid hosting it on e.g. S3?
Note: I am just using the basic heroku/python buildpack.

Comment: There isn't a great way to add it to the slug at build time, though it's probably possible. At runtime, you should be able to just load it from its URL. Unless you want to host a web server on your local machine, no, there's no way to connect your Heroku dyno to your local machine.

Comment: I see, I think I will then download it from a host in a custom buildpack. Does it sound ok?

Comment: Sure, you can try that. I still think loading it when your application starts makes more sense, but as long as you're not low on space pulling it in with a custom buildpack should work.

Comment: Ok, if do that at runtime, will my app download it each time it go off from the sleep mode? (I am not sure how Heroku handles this awaking step)

Comment: Yes, it will do it every time it wakes up. I guess if you're using the free version and your dyno is sleeping frequently that might not be ideal. [S3 charges for egress](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

Comment: Ok! That is why I would prefer to include it while building ;)

Comment: Yep, you've convinced me :-).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have uploaded it at build time in the slug.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: please refer to the discussion with @chris in my original question